# Install and connect to Telnet [Console Application]

Tags: c#, console-application, telnet

Since i finished my School-Project and there is nothing left for now, I started to implement a Easteregg in my little Console Application. It should install telnet `(pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient")` and call the StarWars animation: `"telnet" + "o" + "towel.blinkenlights.nl"`

To do that, my Application opens up a CMD-Prompt, which installs Telnet:

```
public static void EastereggInstall()
    {
        Process cmd = new Process();

        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        cmd.Start();

        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("pkgmgr /iu:'TelnetClient'");
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

After the Task is finished with `Environment.Exit(0);` it calls another CMD-prompt to connect to the telnet Server which starts the Animation:

```
public static void EastereggPlay()
    {
        Process cmd = new Process();

        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        cmd.Start();

        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("telnet" + "o" + "towel.blinkenlights.nl");
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

However, the first Commandprompt closes itself with no Error-message whatsoever. 
I've also tried to use `Console.ReadKey()` to get the Error, but still no useful info there. My first thought was that `cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("telnet" + "o" + "towel.blinkenlights.nl");` can't be executed by using it in a single line, so i tried

```
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("telnet");
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("o");
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("towel.blinkenlights.nl");
```

Still no success. So do you guys know what i should do to get this piece of Code to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

startInfo.Arguments = "/c telnet o towel.blinkenlights.nl";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

make sure that command works because the cmd process will just exit if not.

to make sure everything works, try something like

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/c ping google.com -t";
```

also, while testing you should consider setting `CreateNoWindow` to `false`

Answer (score 1):

Environment.Exit(0) close the whole environment.

You should close only process, so the code can reach the telnet connection.